# Java Local Network Chat

Tags: java, chat

I have spent much time researching how to create a chat system that would work between computers on the same local network, and so far have had no success (in Java). Could anyone provide me with references to things that actually work, or guide me?

Comment: You could take a look at [All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) for starters and maybe even [Socket Communications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems. One is discovery, the other is connections.
For discovery on the local network you want mDNS aka Bonjour.

[jMDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) offers a pure java Bonjour implementation.

You need to setup a service advertisement and a service discovery.
Once you discover a service you can then connect to the daemon you have setup on each machine.

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: Then feel free to mark the answer as an answer so that it is accepted and others don't think you still need an answer.

Comment: There is a countdown and I am waiting to do so

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful resources that I found on Google.

```
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eANjtQ6wJv0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eANjtQ6wJv0
```

There are many more if you just ask "how to make a LAN chat program in Java" in your favorite search engine. There are tutorials online, but it is recommended that you are pretty competent in the language as well as networking. Go back to the basics and read a bunch of books on Java.

For future reference, don't ask questions like that on Stack Exchange. Put problems that you have about code. Be specific!

Comment: Thank you for this as well, these resources will help me in my quest to chat!